# Can the pressure term in the general thrust equation be negative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rocket-science

In the general thrust equation, it looks like the pressure term can be negative if the ambient pressure is greater than the nozzle exit pressure:

$$F=\dot m\cdot V_\mathrm e+\left(p_\mathrm e-p_\mathrm0\right)\cdot A_\mathrm e$$

However, this has some obvious and strange implications. Lowering mass flow to zero and increasing the exit area of the nozzle I can optimize thrust in the opposite direction and create a rocket engine that can accelerate backwards at ludicrous speeds.

Can the pressure term become negative in real-world applications? Are there limitations to how negative it can become?

Comment: If the ambient pressure is greater than the nozzle exit pressure, doesn't that mean your rocket engine is sucking in air through the nozzle?

Comment: You should define all the terms in the equation. Also, I googled "general thrust equation" and it appears that it applies not to a rocket with an ambient pressure of Po as implied by the question but to a jet engine with an inlet pressure of Po.

Comment: Pe is exit pressure and P0 is ambient pressure. Here are a couple of references showing the equation used for rockets:
https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/rockth.html
http://braeunig.us/space/index.htm

Comment: The term for this is an *overexpanded* nozzle, and if you push too far in that direction the flow becomes unstable. ([This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_engine_nozzle#Atmospheric_use) is probably a good starting point.) If you keep pushing, if I understand correctly, this is often associated with catastrophic self-disassembly by the engine.

Comment: Thanks! That's good to know: 

> Slight overexpansion causes a slight reduction in efficiency, but otherwise does little harm. However, if the exit pressure is less than approximately 40% that of ambient, then "flow separation" occurs. This can cause jet instabilities that can cause damage to the nozzle or simply cause control difficulties of the vehicle or the engine.